# Woocommerce - Exclude an Attribute from a Specific Variation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Since a variation row includes all predefined attributes, there is no option to exclude/hide the attributes that you don't need (for a specific row).

In the test below, I've added some attributes and values separated by vertical pipes | (just in case: I'm not using any attributes from Products -> Attributes)
[image: Attributes]

Let's say there is no "Accessories" for the product #2 and I need to exclude it.

**The tricks I'm using right now to bypass it (THIS IS NOT WHAT I WANT)**

I added another value to the "Accessories" attribute like "None" or "N/A" and picked this value for product #2.

Result: product #2 disappears when the customer selects Option 1, Option 2 or Option 3 for the product #1

I tried another trick. I added Option 1, Option 2 and Option 3 Accessories to the product #2 as well and set their "Stock status" to "Out of stock" and their price to 0.

Results: messy and confusing! customers will have no idea which one of the options in the drop-down menus is the cause of "Out of stock" unless they keep switching randomly to dismiss the message and find the right product.

I also found a code to gray out "Out of stock" attributes:

```
function wcbv_variation_is_active( $active, $variation ) {
 if( ! $variation->is_in_stock() ) {
 return false;
 }
 return $active;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_active', 'wcbv_variation_is_active', 10, 2 );
```

but then again it's the similar scenario. you can't pick the grayed out attributes unless you find the right combination for them:

**What I need**

Now I was thinking maybe the only possible solution would be a code snippet to exclude the unnecessary attributes (instead of the tricks that I'm using for the time being). it can be excluded as an option in drop-down menus like this:
[image]

or by marking a check box next to each attribute like this:
[image]

I'm just wondering why wouldn't Woocommerce add such an important feature to their plugin! now the question is, is it possible to fix the issue through a snippet ?

Comment: Woocommerce uses variations where you put for each variation quantity. You can exclude variations with out of stock and user will see only available. Even if you dont do that woocommerce prints out of stock for each variation.